# Smart contract and Oracle contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, blockchain

I have 2 contracts: my contract and an oracle contract. I make a request to my smart contract and send some data that needs to be processed. I use mySmartContract.methods.availability(value1,value2).send({"from":myAddress}).

After my contract gets the data, it has to make an asynchronous request to the oracle smart contract which takes information from an external data source. I read the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55302995/how-to-return-value-to-caller-function-in-asynchronous-javascript-and-web3js, but in my case who calls the 'caller' function on my smart contrac that calls 'responder' on the oracle smart contract?

Comment: `it has to make an asynchronous request to the oracle smart contract which takes information from an external data source` - wrong description.

Comment: `it has to make a (obviously synchronous) request to the oracle smart contract, which is updated asynchronously by an offchain service which takes information from an external data source` - right description.

Comment: `who calls the 'caller' function on my smart contrac that calls 'responder' on the oracle smart contract?` - an offchain service (a bot if you will) that you need to set up, since you're the one who has the credentials (i.e., the private key of `myAddress`).

Comment: @goodvibration I am approaching blockchain and smart contracts for the first time. I am using web3js. can you give me an example with code?

Answer (score 1):

> Who calls the function on my contract that calls the function on the oracle contract?

An offchain service that you need to set up, since you're the one with the private key of `myAddress`.

For example, with web3.js v1.2, you could do something like this:

```
const transaction = mySmartContract.methods.availability(value1, value2);
const options = {
    to      : transaction._parent._address,
    data    : transaction.encodeABI(),
    gas     : await transaction.estimateGas({from: myAddress}),
    gasPrice: yourDesiredGasPrice
};
const signed = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, myAddressPrivateKey);
const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
```

Comment: but after this, my smart contract needs to call a function on the oracle smart contract.  how does it happen?

Comment: @MarioRoma: You need to call the oracle contract function from your contract function (i.e., it's a piece of code that you add in your contract).